# Timing application and exact timestamps from server - serverless?

Tags: python, node.js, timestamp, backend, serverless

I would like developers to give a comment about :) thank you

I am building an application that needs an exact timestamp for multiple devices at the same time. Device time cannot be used, because they are not at the same time.

Asking time from the server is Ok but it is slow and depend on connection speed, and if making this as serverless/regioness then serverside timestamp cannot be used because of time-zones?

On demo application, this works fine with one backend at pointed region but still it needs to respond faster to clients.

[Here is simply image to see this in another way?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2drI.jpg)

In the image, there are no IDs etc but the main idea is there

I am planning to build this on nodejs server and later when more timing calculations translate it to python/Django pack...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using server time is perfectly fine and timezone difference due to different regions can be easily adjusted in code. If you are using a cloud provider, they typically group their services by region instead of distributing them worldwide, so adjusting the timezone shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, check the docs for the cloud service you are planning to use, they usually clearly document the geographic distribution.

Alternatively, you could consider implementing (or using) [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (NTP) on your devices. It's a fairly simple protocol for synchronizing clocks, if you need a source code example take a look at the source for [node-ntp-client](https://github.com/moonpyk/node-ntp-client/blob/master/lib/ntp-client.js) , a javascript implementation.

Comment: Thank you Mihai! One of my friends earlier told also to try synchronizing devices - your comment confirms it - so why not to test it out, good study case for protocol anyway :)